# Left 4 Dead local co-op for 4 players

Tags: xbox-360, left-4-dead

Does the original Left 4 Dead support local co-op for 4 players?  Not using XBox Live but physically sitting in the same room looking at the same tv.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Left 4 Dead and its sequel both support [2 players maximum](http://www.co-optimus.com/game/130/xbox-360/left-4-dead.html) in local co-op mode on the Xbox 360.

You can, however, join a campaign game lobby with a team of two local players and round out the game with 2 more.  Alternatively, you can System Link 2 Xboxes with 2 TVs and play 4 player in the same room (assuming all of this gear fits in the same room ;) )